# Is it possible to inherit members as pointers?

Tags: c++, oop

I want to if it's possible to inherit members as pointers.

```
struct base 
{
    int x, y;
};
struct derived : public base 
{   
    // inherit x and y as int pointers
}
```

It doesn't have to look like the example above, as long as the behavior is similar.

I'm want to use this for SOA(Structure of Arrays) .

pseudo code:

```
template<size, return_type, ...traits>
struct Soa<size, return_type, traits...> {
    Soa<size, return_type, traits...>()
    {
        /*
            buld the rdata as something like this
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                rdata[i] = {&get<I>(soa_data)[i]...}; 
            }
        */
    }

    second_type : public return_type
    {
        // inherit members as pointers
    }

    return_type &operator[](int i)
    {
        return (return_type &)rdata[i];
    }
    tuple<traits[size]...> soa_data;
    second_type rdata[size];

};
// sample use of the Soa
struct base {
    int x, y;
};
Soa<100, base, int, int> soa; // where the two ints correspond to the members of base
base &b = soa[i];
```

Or maybe I'm thinking of the problem the wrong way?

Comment: Not the way you have presented, no.  The actual `int`s are inherited as-is.  What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: What do you mean "inherit as int pointers"? Can you give an example?

Comment: If you could post about the problem you're trying to solve with this? There may be a different solution that could work and help you with it.

Comment: "as long as the behavior is similar." the "above" does not do what you want, so you should explain what behaviour you want. eg. do you need `base` as a base class?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the type of an inherited variable.  But there's nothing to prevent you from creating new variables that point to the parent ones.

```
struct base 
{
    int x, y;
};
struct derived : public base 
{
    int *px, *py;
    derived() : px(&x), py(&y)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy construction or copy assignment will break this though. The [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) applies here.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I didn't mean for this to be a complete example, just a pointer on what was possible. The original question is not very clear.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Rule of 3/5/0 actually *doesn't* apply here. This is one of the rare exceptions. To fix the class only copy constructor and assignment are needed, contrary to rule of 3/5 which would imply the need for a custom destructor.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to inherit members as pointers?

No.

Derived class has a base sub object, which has exactly the members that the base class would have if it weren't a sub object. There is no way to affect what type of members you get from a base.